# Eastwood linter not disabling deprecation warnings

Tags: clojure, static-analysis

Using [Eastwood](https://github.com/jonase/eastwood), I'm trying to disable deprecation warnings, for a specific package, when linting a given Clojure namespace. In this case, eastwood is failing  when making a Google API call which is deprecated.

As per [the documentation](https://github.com/jonase/eastwood#deprecations), I tried to disable the linter for that package.

```
λ cat src/main/resources/third-party-libs.clj

(disable-warning
  {:linter :deprecations
   :symbol-matches #{"^#'com\.google\.api\.core\.*'"}})
```

But no dice. How can I turn off deprecation for specific classes or packages?

```
my/namespace.clj:13:5: deprecations: Static method 'public static void com.google.api.core.ApiFutures.addCallback(com.google.api.core.ApiFuture,com.google.api.core.ApiFutureCallback)' is deprecated.
```

**EDIT**

A) I'm able to load `src/main/resources/my-eastwood-config.clj`. But `com.google.api.core.ApiFutures.*` still isn't ignored.

```
(disable-warning
  {:linter :deprecations
   :symbol-matches #{#"com\.google\.api\.core\.ApiFutures.*"}})
```

B) Either of these formats gives me the error below.

i)

```
(disable-warning
  {:linter :deprecations
   :symbol-matches #{"^#'com\.google\.api\.core\..*'"}})

(disable-warning
  {:linter :deprecations
   :symbol-matches #{"^#'com\\.google\\.api\\.core\\..*'"}})
```

ii)

```
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported escape character: \., compiling:(null:4:31)
        clojure.lang.Compiler.load (Compiler.java:7521)
        clojure.lang.Compiler.load (Compiler.java:7461)
        clojure.core/load-reader (core.clj:4053)
        clojure.core/load-reader (core.clj:4048)
        eastwood.util/init-warning-enable-config/fn--40733 (util.clj:916)
        eastwood.util/init-warning-enable-config (util.clj:914)
        eastwood.util/init-warning-enable-config (util.clj:907)
        eastwood.lint/last-options-map-adjustments (lint.clj:467)
        eastwood.lint/last-options-map-adjustments (lint.clj:456)
        eastwood.lint/eastwood (lint.clj:511)
        eastwood.lint/eastwood (lint.clj:501)
        eastwood.lint/eastwood (lint.clj:502)
        eastwood.lint/eastwood (lint.clj:501)
        eastwood.lint/eastwood-from-cmdline (lint.clj:529)
        eastwood.lint/eastwood-from-cmdline (lint.clj:528)
        clojure.lang.Var.invoke (Var.java:381)
        eastwood.versioncheck/run-eastwood (versioncheck.clj:15)
        eastwood.versioncheck/run-eastwood (versioncheck.clj:9)
        user/eval39298 (form-init6182731209880131993.clj:1)
        user/eval39298 (form-init6182731209880131993.clj:1)
        clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:7062)
        clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:7052)
        clojure.lang.Compiler.load (Compiler.java:7514)
        clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile (Compiler.java:7452)
        clojure.main/load-script (main.clj:278)
        clojure.main/init-opt (main.clj:280)
        clojure.main/init-opt (main.clj:280)
        clojure.main/initialize (main.clj:311)
        clojure.main/null-opt (main.clj:345)
        clojure.main/null-opt (main.clj:342)
        clojure.main/main (main.clj:424)
        clojure.main/main (main.clj:387)
        clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:702)
clojure.main.main (main.java:37)
```

Comment: Make sure to understand Clojure's syntax for regular expressions. In `#"..."` you must escape a dot with one backslash, while if you use plan strings like `"..."` you need two backslashes. One to escape the backslash in the string and the remaining to escape the dot. Also, is it possible that you have a single quote too many at the end of some of your regexps? Could it be a left over of automatic pair insertion in your editor?

Answer (score 1):

*Eastwood* is not picking up your config file.  You can debug this with:

```
lein eastwood '{:debug [:config]}'
== Eastwood 0.3.7 Clojure 1.10.1 JVM 1.8.0_242 ==
Loading config file: jar:file:$HOME/.m2/repository/jonase/eastwood/0.3.7/eastwood-0.3.7.jar!/eastwood/config/clojure.clj
Loading config file: jar:file:$HOME/.m2/repository/jonase/eastwood/0.3.7/eastwood-0.3.7.jar!/eastwood/config/clojure-contrib.clj
Loading config file: jar:file:$HOME/.m2/repository/jonase/eastwood/0.3.7/eastwood-0.3.7.jar!/eastwood/config/third-party-libs.clj
...
```

The reason, why a similar named file is not picked up:

> You can specify the key :builtin-config-files in the options map to
>   override the built-in config files read. It defaults to ["clojure.clj"
>   "clojure-contrib.clj" "third-party-libs.clj"]. **All such file names are
>   only looked for in Eastwood's built-in config files.**
>
> Similarly you can specify :config-files in the options map to give
>   additional files to read. These are file names that can be anywhere in
>   your file system, specified as strings, or if Eastwood is invoked from
>   the REPL, anything that can be passed to clojure.java.io/reader.
>
> ---
>
> Source: https://github.com/jonase/eastwood#eastwood-config-files

Not very specific, but that would imply they are looked up as resources
under `/eastwood/config/...`.

If you would put a file under that same location with the same name you may
or may not win against the default configs (e.g. one wins).  So the way out is to
specify the config just yourself.  E.g.

```
lein eastwood '{:config-files ["eastwood-config.clj"] :debug [:config]}' 
== Eastwood 0.3.7 Clojure 1.10.1 JVM 1.8.0_242 ==
Loading config file: jar://...
...
Loading config file: eastwood-config.clj
...
```

Also watch out with your regexp.  I think you want: `"^#'com\.google\.api\.core\..*'"` (note the additional `.` before the `*`); otherwise the `\.` repeats.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was able to make a config file reference for eastwood. But all of the formats I used either ignored the `disable-warning` ... Or blew up when trying to read the config.

Comment: I think you want to use `#"^#'com\.google\.api\.core\..*'"` - i don't have the google library to reproduce it (that is a regexp for fully qualified a symbol).

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Neither **A** nor **B** work to disable the deprecation warning.

**A)** `#"^#'com\.google\.api\.core\.ApiFutures*'"` 
**B)** `#"^#'com\.google\.api\.core\..*'"`

Comment: I can take look at this futher, but i'd like to request a minimal failing example - i'll not dig into some google OO mess on my own ;)

Comment: I created a `.tgz` file with a simple example lein project. Just go in there, and run `lein eastwood`. You should see the error. (https://transfer.sh/%28Could%20not%20save%20metadata%29.tar.gz)

Comment: The link there downloads as 66 bytes and refuses to gunzip.   Could you share that project in github or create a gist of the three files involved (project.clj, your eastood config, and the clj file with the offending import)

Comment: Hmm, ok sorry about that. Try this repo. github.com/twashing/eastwood-example