# How to tell eastwood ignore deprecated namespaces

Tags: clojure, deprecated

Got to my hands some old code, and now trying to adopt eastwood as linter. when doing that eastwood says that it has some code that is deprecated for example in ns `x.y.z I` have a require for `[a.b :as b]` and I want this required to be ignore from eastwood! can i do that?

I have tried the followed, in variation of the regex with no success:

```
(disable-warning
  {:linter :deprecations
   :symbol-matches #{#"^a\.b\.*"}})
```

any idea?

Comment: Are you sure, your config file is picked up?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60268709/eastwood-linter-not-disabling-deprecation-warnings/60281194

Comment: Well, yes. I am pretty sure since running it in debug show it does :)

Comment: Are you sure your regex is correct? Do you mean to match a.b and then everything after that with `.*`? In which case shouldn't it be: `^a\.b.*`?

Comment: Well I took the regex from the clojure docs of eastwood itself. Also the \. is an escaping, isn't it a must?
Anyhow tried that - didn't work
I want to ignore for example a.b/c

Comment: So finally I have decided to ignore to entire linter by disabling it using:
`:exclude-linters [:deprecations :constant-test]`
Don't like it but this the only way I could make it work :(